# Integrate Laravel application into Shopify Storefront

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce, shopify, shopify-app

Are there any Shopify **"Embedded App SDK"** in the **Shopify Storefront** rather than in the **Shopify Admin**?

Like in the illustration below, *Letter A* is already available in the **Shopify SDK** (https://help.shopify.com/api/sdks/shopify-apps/embedded-app-sdk).
But currently as of this writing, what we would like to do is illustrated in *letter B*

[image]

Is this possible? Or do you guys have any suggestions on how to handle this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you considered any idea til now? any try? show us something on what is your idea, then others can more easily value if it is feasible or not in that way or if is totally wrong.

Comment: Hi @sissy. I just continued my research today. I'll be updating this issue whenever I found a solution to it. First I'll consider what Josh Brown answered.

Comment: Hi  @sissy. [App proxies](https://help.shopify.com/api/tutorials/application-proxies) worked very well for me. All the information was well said on the answer below. :)

Comment: Good. Then you could also accept the answer @josh brown gave you, or either upvote it if it helped :)

Comment: Accepted. :) 
I can't upvote yet cause I have low reputation. Also upvote the question please? Thank you.

Cheers.

Comment: acceptance is enough don't worry. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can incorporate your app into a storefront using [app proxies](https://help.shopify.com/api/tutorials/application-proxies) or [ScriptTags](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/scripttag).

ScriptTags allow your app to load third-party JavaScript on existing pages of the store. This is useful if you want to render a widget (like a live chat system) on product pages, collection pages and/or the homepage.

If you register an app proxy then that will create a path on the storefront (e.g. kith.com/apps/your-app) that is specific to your app. Shopify will proxy those requests to your server and you can respond with the content that should be served to the customer.

Comment: I'll look up into that. Thank you!